# Writing function prototypes for templates that use auto return type deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently learning about templates and arrived upon the topic of auto type deductions for return types. After some experimentation, I came to the conclusion that function prototypes may not be written for functions that use `decltype(auto)` or `auto` as return types as in the following:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const auto plus(const T1 a, const T2 b);
```

or

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(auto) plus(const T1 a, const T2 b);
```

If these prototypes are defined before `main()` the compiler can't deduce the return type from the function prototype, is that correct?

would an alternative solution then be something like a trailing auto return type?

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto plus(const T1 a, const T2 a) -> decltype(a + b);
```

This is all under the assumption that these functions are being defined in the same file after the call to `main()`

Comment: This is a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file why you don't need `-> decltype(a + b)`.

Comment: *"the compiler can't deduce the return type from the function prototype, is that correct?"* -- perhaps ask yourself a similar question: can **you** deduce the return type from the function prototype? *(No fair guessing based upon the function name -- based only on the signature `const auto(const T1, const T2)` and given two types, what type is returned?)*